# mariadb 10.2 json insert fails

Tags: php, json, apache, mariadb, fedora-27

I just upgraded from Fedora-25 to Fedora-27 on my server and I have a few issues. When I submit a new record via website into into some of my tables the insert fails. I can enter data from Access via ODBC into some but not all Tables.

The insert is getting a NULL value for the linenumber column from JSON handler on the webpage. If I remove the LineNumber and variable from the insert statement it works. I can edit, update works fine for this form.

I have another table that I insert to get a new LoadNumber and that works but it will not update but I can edit update from Access via ODBC and one table the I can not enter data from Access but I can from phpmyadmin then edit it in Access. I don't have a page for this table on my site. All of these forms worked fine previous to the upgrade.

```
$LN=$_POST['LineNumber'];
$SLN=$_POST['SLNS'];
$TypeId=$_POST['TypeId'];
$StopNbr=$_POST['StopNumber'];
$RN=$_POST['ReferenceNo'];
$LID=$_POST['LocationId'];


//inserting data order
$order = "INSERT INTO tblStops          (LineNumber,LoadNumber,TypeId,StopNumber,ReferenceNo,LocationId)
VALUES(
        '$LN','$SLN','$TypeId','$StopNbr','$RN','$LID')
    ";

$order1 =  "UPDATE tblStops SET lineNumber = '$LN', LoadNumber = '$SLN', TypeId = '$TypeId', StopNumber = '$StopNbr', ReferenceNo = '$RN', LocationId = '$LID'
WHERE lineNumber = '$LN'";
//declare in the order variable

if (($LN)>0 )
    {
    $result=mysqli_query($mysqli,$order1);
    } else{echo
    $result=mysqli_query($mysqli,$order);
    }
    if($result){
    header('location: loads.php');
    } else{
        echo("Data Input Failed");
    }
flush();
```

Comment: Your code probably breaks for the same reason that it's vulnerable to SQL injection. Use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) and you'll fix two birds with one stone.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I will make the adjustments, I hope it works. The code has been working fine for a number of years now and broke after the upgrade I didn't know why or which component changed mariadb or php. This is something I wrote for my company, I am clearly not a programmer.

Comment: I changed this to use prepared statements and id din't solve my problem. The issue was the quotes on $LN as this variable is null. I changed '$LN' to NULL problem solved. I could have also left off that column all together as it is auto increment. I don't know why it worked previously.

Comment: @CriagKuyper - I assume $LN came from a `<form>`?  If nothing was entered, it will be the empty string, not NULL.

Comment: Yes that's correct, I check to see if there is a value to determine weather to insert or update. The change is in the mariadb it no longer accepts empty strings as "dummy" null. Once I figured out what was wrong I found out why. There were a few other columns in other tables that had a similar issue, null ok default none, those are corrected now too.

Answer (score 0):

A change in mariadb was the issue.

From the MariaDB site.

SQL_MODE has been changed; in particular, NOT NULL fields with no default will no longer fall back to a dummy value for inserts which do not specify a value for that field.